Memory efficient way to decode large JSON string
I have a very big string (500 MB in size) and I need to json_decode it, with this code:
$xxx = json_decode($xxx);

I am using the same variable to override its content in order to use the least amount of memory possible. Despite doing so, the memory usage more than double for a few seconds when the json_decode function runs. Is there a way to make the json_encode reduce the contents of $xxx while decoding the string (read 100 bytes from $xxx, parse 100 bytes and remove 100 bytes from $xxx).
My server has only 4GB of memory and reading a 500MB string uses all memory.

You could use a custom library that decode json with file size taken into consideration (using buffer stream for example), example: https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine. You could also split the file into smaller size files (quite easy to do if your json is basically a huge collection of objects)

May I ask what the file comes from? Are you creating it, or does it come from some external source? Is it always new data, or can it contain things you already have? If you generate the file to begin with, then you could save it in multiple files instead?
